# Flask deployment on Azure fails with 503 - Server Unavailable

Tags: azure, docker, flask, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

on Azure I am trying to deploy a flask API on a web app hosted on Linux. The code of the `app.py` is the following:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
from db_helpers import init_db

app.config[
    'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'
] = my_microsoft_azure_database_connection.database_connection_uri
app.config['DEBUG'] = False
app.config['TESTING'] = False
app.config['CSRF_ENABLED'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'needs-to-be-changed'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db_engine = init_db()
db = SQLAlchemy(app, metadata=BaseDeclarative.metadata)

api = Api(app, default_mediatype='application/json')

api.add_resource(
    ListAssessmentCaseEndpoint, '/assessments', endpoint='list_assessment_cases'
)
api.add_resource(
    AssessmentCaseEndpoint, '/assessments/<uuid:uuid>', endpoint='assessment_cases'
)

api.add_resource(ListAuditLogEndpoint, '/auditing', endpoint='list_audit_logs')
api.add_resource(AuditLogEndpoint, '/auditing/<uuid:uuid>', endpoint='audit_logs')

api.add_resource(HealthCheckEndpoint, '/healthcheck', endpoint='health_check')


# Add Swagger documentation to Flask app
Swagger(app, template_file='swagger.yml')
```

In order to deploy the application on Azure, we first build an artifact (zip file) using the following ARM template:

```
trigger:
- develop

variables:

  webAppName: 'test-api'

  environmentName: 'test-api'

  projectRoot: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/WebApi

  pythonVersion: '3.7'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
      displayName: 'Use Python $(pythonVersion)'
    
    - script: |
        python3 -m venv .venv
        source .venv/bin/activate
        pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install waitress==2.1.2
        pip install setup
        pip install -r requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
      displayName: "Install requirements"

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(projectRoot)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(webAppName).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(webAppName).zip
      displayName: 'Upload package'
      artifact: drop
```

We then deploy the artifact on a Web App (hosted on linux using Python 3.7). To do that, we use the following template:

```
steps:
- task: AzureWebApp@1
  displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: test-api'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'azurerm-sp-apps-dev'
    appType: webAppLinux
    appName: 'testt-api'
    package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test-api-WebApi/drop/test-api.zip'
    runtimeStack: 'PYTHON|3.7'
    startUpCommand: 'python3.7 -m pip install -r requirements.txt && python3.7 -m pip install gunicorn && python3.7 -m gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:80 --workers=4 app:app'
    configurationStrings: '-StartupCommand startup.sh'
    deploymentMethod: zipDeploy
```

and we also use an application gateway that is configured as the following:

```
steps:
- task: test-AppGateway.appGatewayCreate-task.test-AppGateway-CreateUpdate@1
  displayName: 'Create or Update Application Gateway Config API'
  inputs:
    connectedServiceName: 'azurerm-sp-apps-dev'
    AppName: 'test-api'
    HealthProbeUri: /healthcheck
  timeoutInMinutes: 120
  retryCountOnTaskFailure: 10
```

But at the deployment, we have the following strange behaviours:

1 + In the application logs (in the availability and Performance menu), we can see that the gunicorn server has been started correctly and that it is listening on http://0.0.0.0:80, and that the 4 workers have been booted...

2 + But in the platform logs, we have the following errors:

```
Platform logs contain errors or warnings
Container test-api_0_a8607b6c for site test-api did not start within expected time limit.
Container test-api_0_a8607b6c didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start
```

We have investigated the issue and here are some solutions that we tried, but did not work:

- Increase the value of `WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT`: currently we set it to 1800
- Change he the value of `WEBSITES_PORT`: tried to 8000 and 80
- Change the startup command used to start the flask rest api: tried waitress-serve, gunicorn, and flask so far
- We also tried to change the port number to start the flask server: 80, 5000, 8000m 8081

3 + This leads for the `/healthcheck` endpoint to not respond (503 server unavailable leading to 502 bad gateway on the application gateway)

4 + another issue encountered is that for some reason, the virtual environment created during the build time is not recognized at the deployment phase:

- we receive the following command when we try to activate it: `/opt/startup/startup.sh: startup.sh: not found name source not found`
- also we noticed that the python version used during the deployment is different from the virtual environment that we defined

this is the following docker command used internally at the deployment:

```
docker run -d -p 9286:8000 --expose=49494 --name test-api_0_f5ccb0ab -e WEBSITE_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=https://test.dev.app.test.com,https://test.eastus2-dev-platform-ase1.appserviceenvironment.net -e WEBSITE_CORS_SUPPORT_CREDENTIALS=True -e WEBSITES_PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=test-api -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=test-api.eastus2-dev-platform-ase1.appserviceenvironment.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=MY-ID -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=True appsvc/python:3.7_20221128.12.tuxprod python3.7 -m pip install -r requirements.txt && python3.7 -m pip install gunicorn && python3.7 -m gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:80 --workers=4 app:app
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending much time trying to find the source of the problem; I finally made the rest api work correctly by changing the startup command to the following:

```
gunicorn -w 2 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app:app
```

now all the errors are gone and the web app is fully functional. Also, you have to add the following to `requirements.txt`:

```
gunicorn~=20.1.0
uvicorn~=0.20.0
```